# ERROR: function random_integer(integer, integer) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table for PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    building_id bigint NOT NULL,
    login_name character varying(255),
    status character varying(10), // it can be enabled/disabled
    created_at timestamp(6)
)
```

I wan to create a test data using this SQL query:

```
insert into users
select n, 
       random_integer(1,100), 
       random_string(20), 
       random_date(date (current_date + interval '3 days'), date '2016-12-31'), 
from generate_series (1, 100) n;
```

But I get error:

> ERROR: function random_integer(integer, integer) does not exist

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: None of these `random_*`  functions exists in Postgres, as far as I know. Did you find them in the documentation?

Comment: ok, can you advice how I can generate test data, please?

Comment: Why would you need random data to start with? It is simpler to generate a deterministic series of data to fill in your table, based on the output of `generate_series` . Eg for column `login_name`:  `'user01'` , `'user02'` , ... And the same type of logic can be applied for other columns.

Comment: I need 10000 rows of random data to test pagination and response time.

Comment: Why did you think these functions would exist in PostgreSQL? None of these is not mentioned in the manual

Answer (score 0):

The following generates 10,000 sample rows:

```
WITH p(num_samples, num_buildings, min_created_at, max_created_at) AS (
  SELECT 10000, 100, '2019-01-01'::TIMESTAMP, '2023-12-31'::TIMESTAMP
),
samples AS (
  SELECT GEN_RANDOM_UUID() AS id,
         (RANDOM() * p.num_buildings)::BIGINT + 1 AS building_id,
         GEN_RANDOM_UUID() AS login_name,
         CASE WHEN random() < 0.5 THEN 'disabled' ELSE 'enabled' END AS status,
         p.min_created_at + INTERVAL '1' SECOND * (RANDOM() * EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM p.max_created_at - p.min_created_at))::INTEGER AS created_at
    FROM p CROSS JOIN GENERATE_SERIES(1, num_samples) t(n))
INSERT INTO users(id, building_id, login_name, status, created_at)
  SELECT id, building_id, login_name, status, created_at
    FROM samples;
```

The first CTE, `p`, establishes the generation parameters. `GEN_RANDOM_UUID` is used to create random strings for `login_name` since the actual text is not important.